# SetWindowsHookExA на функцию член класса

Tags: c++, winapi

Пытаюсь отловить `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` и `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` сообщения для окна, дескриптор которого является членом класса. Для этого использую `SetWindowsHookExA` с параметром `WH_GETMESSAGE`. Второй параметр функции (`HOOKPROC`) указывает на функцию, внутри моего класса:

```
class WindowDisplayHelper : // public ...
{    
public:
    // some other public methods here
    void SetMsgHook();
protected:
    LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProcHook(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK MsgPoc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
private:
    // some other private members there
    HWND m_windowHandle;
    bool m_isWindowResizing = false;
    static HHOOK m_msgHook;
    static WindowsDisplayHelperMasterWindow* m_pThis;
};
```

.cpp файл:

```
WindowDisplayHelper* WindowDisplayHelper ::m_pThis = nullptr;
HHOOK WindowDisplayHelper ::m_msgHook = NULL;

void WindowDisplayHelper ::SetMsgHook()
{
    m_pThis = this;
    m_msgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, MsgPoc, NULL, 0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowDisplayHelper::MsgPoc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (m_pThis != nullptr)
    {
        return m_pThis->GetMsgProcHook(code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowDisplayHelper::GetMsgProcHook(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DUMPER_INFO("Hooked");
    if (code < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    MSG* lpmsg = (MSG*)lParam;
    DUMPER_INFO("Hooked for HWND: %p. Current window %p", lpmsg->hwnd, m_windowHandle);
    if (lpmsg->hwnd != m_windowHandle)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    if (lpmsg->message == WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE && !m_isWindowResizing)
    {
        DUMPER_INFO("Start window resizing");
        m_isWindowResizing = true;
    }
    else if (lpmsg->message == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE && m_isWindowResizing)
    {
        DUMPER_INFO("Stop window resizing");
        m_isWindowResizing = false;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Процес создания объекта `WindowDisplayHelper`:

```
auto helper = boost::make_shared<WindowDisplayHelper>(windowHandle);
helper->SetMsgHook();
AddDisplayHelper(displayId, helper);

return true;
```

И хотя я и вызываю `SetMsgHook` после создания объекта `WindowDisplayHelper`, выглядит так, будто хук не устанавливается: `m_isWindowResizing` все время == false и логов не видно этих. Т.к. обработчик хука находится внутри класса, то пришлось прибегнуть к приемам со статическим указателем на this, но что-то это не сработало. Пробовал указать id потока (результат `GetCurrentThreadId`), но это тоже не помогло.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не срабатывает моя функция обработки оконных сообщений?

Comment: В коде отсутствует проверка  успешности установки хука. Два нулевых последних параметра в `SetWindowsHookEx` выглядят подозрительно. Непонятно, откуда берется m_windowHandle?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то эта проблема обычно решается немного иначе. В частности, для хранения ссылки на экземпляр класса используется не статическое поле, а само окно.

Адрес экземпляра класса указывается при создании окна как аргумент `CreateWindowEx`:

```
m_hwndControl = ::CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, MY_WINDOW_CLASS, _TEXT(""),
        WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE,
        rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top,
        m_hwndParent, (HMENU)uID, hInstance, this);
```

А связывание с экземпляром класса выполняется в оконной процедуре.

```
// WndProc является статической функцией-членом!
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindow::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    // Get pointer to self

    MyWindow *pSelf;
    if (uMsg == WM_CREATE) {
        pSelf = (MyWindow*)(((CREATESTRUCT*)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
        ::SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pSelf);
    }
    else
        pSelf = (MyWindow*)::GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

    // Здесь вызываются классовые функции-обработчики, например так:

    // Dispatch message

    switch (uMsg) {
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_CREATE,         pSelf->OnCreate);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_DESTROY,        pSelf->OnDestroy);

        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_ERASEBKGND,     pSelf->OnEraseBkgnd);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_PAINT,          pSelf->OnPaint);

    . . .
```

(`HANDLE_MSG` - это message cracker из windowx.h. Использовать крекеры, разумеется, не обязательно.)

В таком виде все будет корректно работать и для нескольких окон.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня другой случай. Мой класс - это не окно, а, скорее, класс, который проверяет состояние (свернуто или нет, перекрыто или нет, позицию и размеры окна) этого окна в определенный момент времени. Для этого в моем классе есть HWND того окна, для которого мой класс собирает информацию. И вот глобальная задача состоит в том, что бы понять, что в данный конкретный момент времени окно ресайзится. То есть задча сводится к тому, как имея дескриптор окна понять, что оно ресайзится.

Comment: То есть у вас просто не вызывается процедура, заданная в `SetWindowsHookEx`? А у вас разрядность согласуется? Это же по сути внедрение DLL.

Comment: Да, но проблема в том, что у меня не dll, а глобальные хуки можно делать только из dll

Comment: @rudolfninja, вы что, пытаетесь сделать хук из процесса в другой процесс? Тогда не удивительно что ничего не выходит, адресные пространства же разные. Внедряйте dll, а она уже пусть с вашим процссом общается.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я это уже понял. Скорее всего буду реализовывать такое решение